# How do I test if a player moved a certain distance from an area in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I do know how to use @p[r=R] and @p[rm=RM], and I do not want that. I want to find players a certain distance from a command block while ignoring y values.

Example: The players are restricted to a certain circular area with no height limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define that area using [coordinates](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_coordinate) and [volume](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_volume) in the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) of a command that adds a [scoreboard tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags).  Anyone without that tag would then be outside that range.  The only downside in your case is that the defined area will not be circular but square.

This would use two command blocks in a chain.  The first removes the tag from all players.  The second adds the tag only to players inside the area.  These command blocks need to remain loaded so I recommend placing them in the [spawn chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk).

I also recommend preventing command block output to prevent OP players from having their chat filled with command block spam.  Use command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

*First command block* is <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> and it's command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove InArea
```

*Second command block* is <kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> and it's command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dx=DX,dy=DY,dz=DZ] add InArea
```

The two sets of coordinates in the second command target selector are two opposite corners of the area.  In your case, Y could be 1 and DY could be 256.

Now you can target anyone without that tag: `@a[tag=!InArea]`

As an example, lets make them all say hello:

```
/execute @a[tag=!InArea] ~ ~ ~ say Hello
```

Comment: Wow, this is much simpler than I thought. Thanks! It doesn't matter much that it's square.

Comment: much has changed with 1.13, but could you technically just remove the Y and DY selectors, since you don't want that tested?